# Web Content Displayed Incorrectly on Safari

Tags: html, css, image, safari

After creating a quick site, I notice that images either don't show or are incorrectly formatted from Safari on my iPhone and Mac.

For example, I'm expecting `assets/images/showza` under `@keyframes animate` in `index.css` to display at 65% the width of the device, which works on Chrome for Windows 10 but on Safari it actually appears inflated to over 100%.

I suppose I'm looking for any Safari dependencies I may have missed, I'm not used to the discrepancies of web development.

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    animation: animate 16s ease-in-out infinite;
    background-size: cover;
}

.outer{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15)
}

@keyframes animate{
    
    0%,100%{
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showza.png"), url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_1.JPG?raw=true");
        height: 100%;
        
        -webkit-appearance: textfield;

        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 65%, cover;
    }
    33%{
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showza.png"), url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_2.JPG?raw=true");
    }
    66%{
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showza.png"), url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_3.jpg?raw=trueg");
    }
}

.image {
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.itemDiv {
    height: 45px;
}

.item {
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.menuItem {
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;

}
  
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" lang="en">
  <title>
      showzatheband
  </title>
  <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <body class="body">
    <div class="container">
   <div class="outer">
  
          <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a>
              <form name="myform" action="index.html" method="POST">
                <input type="image" class="image" src="assets/images/showzafavcon.jpg" alt="showza_icon" width="125" height="125">
              </form>
            </a>
            <div class="itemDiv"></div>
            <a href="#news">
              <div class="item">
                live dates
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#news">
              <div class="item">
                gallery
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#news">
              <div class="item">
                news
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
              <i class="fa fa-bars">
              <div class="menuItem">
                menu
              </div>
              </i>
            </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use full path for those image source, ex: https://example.com/assets/images/showza.png

Comment: @rangerz I've tried this to no avail, using a GitHub raw format.

Comment: Can you provide an example page to check this out on?

Comment: Also the HTML provided in the example is not valid when I check it here: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Comment: @JasonLydon Hi, I have performed a validation on W3 and can confirm these changes don't fix the problem, I'll have a page set up soon.

Comment: @JasonLydon  Please check my post, I can confirm the snippet doesn't work on Safari for my Mac but works fine on Chrome for Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the core issue appears to be trying to animate with two background images. I didn't find any know bug with "Safari" + "multiple images" but as we can see, it doesn't work as expected. If you remove the logo from that animation, it sort of works in Safari but it's not what I'd call "acceptable".

Like so:

```
66% {
  background-image: url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_3.jpg?raw=trueg");
}
```

Some other pointers:
1. Only animate the thing that changes and move the shared stuff to the main css selector. The values you add in 0 and 100% will only apply there, but I think you want it shared across all states. So it's better in the `.container`

:(

```
.container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    animation: animate 16s ease-in-out infinite;
    background-size: cover;
}
@keyframes animate{
    0%,100%{
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showza.png"), url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_1.JPG?raw=true");
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-appearance: textfield;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 65%, cover;
    }
    33%{
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showza.png"), url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_2.JPG?raw=true");
    }
    66%{
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showza.png"), url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_3.jpg?raw=trueg");
    }
}
```

:)

```
.container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    animation: animate 16s ease-in-out infinite;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 65%, cover;
}
@keyframes animate{
    0%,100%{
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showza.png"), url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_1.JPG?raw=true");
    }
    33%{
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showza.png"), url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_2.JPG?raw=true");
    }
    66%{
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showza.png"), url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_3.jpg?raw=trueg");
    }
}
```

2. Anchors should wrap `div`s when just text is involved. This is my bias but your HTML got that divitis.

:(

```
<a href="#news">
  <div class="item">
    live dates
  </div>
</a>
```

:)

```
<a href="#news" title="Some helpful title" class="item">live dates</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#news" title="Some helpful title"><span class="item">live dates</span></a>
```

3. Also, run your CSS through some form of autoprefixer in hopes of having the best cross browser support. I'm a fan of: https://autoprefixer.github.io/

I rebuilt this how I would do it which involved changing everything to some degree. Hopefully it helps you on your way. It's totally biased yada yada but I think it accomplishes your goals and you can build off it.

```js
// This just creates a timer to change the data-background of the body
window.setInterval(function(){
  var currentBackground = document.body.getAttribute("data-background") * 1,
      nextBackground = currentBackground + 1;
  if (currentBackground >= 3) {
    nextBackground = 1;
  }
  document.body.setAttribute("data-background", nextBackground);
}, 5000);
// menu controls
var toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".topnav");
var toggleMenuButton = toggleMenu.querySelector(" button");
var toggleMenuState = function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var currentState = toggleMenu.getAttribute("data-state");
  if (currentState === "closed") {
    toggleMenu.setAttribute("data-state", "open");
  } else {
    toggleMenu.setAttribute("data-state", "closed");
  }
};
toggleMenuButton.addEventListener("click", toggleMenuState);
```

```css
/* prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io (PostCSS: v7.0.26, autoprefixer: v9.7.3) */

body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.topnav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}
.topnav .logo img {
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.topnav button {
  display: none;
}
.topnav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}
.topnav li {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
.topnav a,
.topnav button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.topnav button {
  border: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.topnav button:before {
  content: "» ";
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}
.topnav[data-state="open"] button:before {
  content: "x ";
}
.topnav a:hover,
.topnav button:hover {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.gallery {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.gallery li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in-out 0.0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in-out 0.0s;
  transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in-out 0.0s;
}
.gallery li:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_1.JPG?raw=true");
}
.gallery li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_2.JPG?raw=true");
}
.gallery li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://github.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/blob/master/assets/images/bg_3.jpg?raw=trueg");
}
[data-background="1"] .gallery li:nth-child(1),
[data-background="2"] .gallery li:nth-child(2),
[data-background="3"] .gallery li:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.hero {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showza.png") rgba(0,0,0,0.15) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 65%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .topnav {
      -webkit-box-pack: justify;
          -ms-flex-pack: justify;
              justify-content: space-between;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .topnav button {
      display: inherit;
    }
    .topnav ul {
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          -ms-flex-direction: column;
              flex-direction: column;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      right: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .topnav ul li {
      -webkit-box-pack: end;
          -ms-flex-pack: end;
              justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .topnav[data-state="closed"] ul {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>showzatheband</title>
    <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body data-background="1">
    <menu class="topnav" data-state="closed">
      <a href="/" title="Homepage" class="logo"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/showzadomain/showzatheband.github.io/master/assets/images/showzafavcon.jpg" alt="showza_icon" width="125" height="125" /></a>
      <button>menu</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#news" class="item">live dates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news" class="item">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news" class="item">news</a></li>
      </ul>
    </menu>
    <div class="hero"></div>
    <ul class="gallery">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the help with this.  I understand this is something build off, but you did a good job explaining what I needed to change; as someone who doesn't do too much web development I really appreciate that.  Also these changes have created a smoother transition, I used to experience flickering during the tween transition.  I've been pulling my hair out over this for the past couple days, so thanks again.

Comment: Also, I can't award the bounty for another 14hrs.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Hey, while I'm very happy with the result, I just noticed that the menu is no longer reactive.  Can you show me how I can make this happen with your refactored code?  Thanks

Comment: @Jake check out the update, should be enough there for you to build from.